# Como puedo asignar un componente de react a una ruta específica con express

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, express

Por ejemplo:
A la ruta http:localhost:4000/start 
Asignar un componente de react 
Teniendo en cuenta que estoy usando node js

Comment: Hola, lo que puedo hacer es  declarar la ruta tanto en reactjs como en el express, pero no te servira de nada. Te sugiero que leas este [post](https://lemoncode.net/lemoncode-blog/2018/5/13/server-side-rendering-i-conceptos), puede que te ayude con  tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes realizar con React Router DOM, declaras la ruta especifica y le indicas el componente que quieras que aparezca en la ruta indicada.

```
      <Route path="/indicas-la-ruta">
        <MiComponente />
      </Route>
```

[Quick Start](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start)

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, hay que agregar la parte esencial de los enlaces, revisa [answer], saludos.